# How Implementing a windows service on a server that is hosted with ISP

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an assignment in asp.net to send notification email to users at specific intervals.

But the problem is that since the server is not privately owned i cannot implement a windows service on it.

Any ideas?

Comment: there is no robust solution for that... use a different server which allows to install Windows Service!

Comment: I do not understand the -1 on a totally new user with a simple question.

Comment: Does the server have a database, e.g. SQL Server, that can run scheduled jobs and send email?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no reliable way to achieve that. If you cannot install a Windows Service on the host you could write a endpoint (`.aspx` or `.ashx`) that will send the email and then purchase on some other site a service which will ping this endpoint at regular intervals by sending it HTTP request. Obviously you should configure this endpoint to be accessible only from the IP address of the provider you purchase the service from, otherwise anyone could send an HTTP request to the endpoint and trigger the process which is probably undesirable.

Further reading: [`The Dangers of Implementing Recurring Background Tasks In ASP.NET`](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to get code executing on an interval that don't require a windows service.

One option is to use the [`Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) class - use one of the [`Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05kd8d77.aspx) overloads that takes a `CacheItemRemovedCallback` - this will be called when the cache item is removed. You can re-add the cache item with this callback again and again...

Though, the first thing you need to do is contact the hosting company and find out if they already have some sort of solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a scheduled task on the server to invoke a program with the desired action.

Comment: "But the problem is that since the server is not privately owned i cannot implement a windows service on it.": does not state scheduled tasks are not possible.  I am capable of reading, thanks.

Comment: I'd have thought it's a pretty logical assumption - i.e. user cannot install a service, probably also true that user can't access task scheduler.

Comment: As far as I know the difference is a requirement for admin privileges

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a `System.Timer` and create a call at specific intervals. What you need to be careful is that this must be run one time, eg on application start, but if you have more than one pools, then it may run more times, and you also need to access some database to read the data of your actions.

```
using System.Timers;

var oTimer = new Timer();

    oTimer.Interval = 30000; // 30 second
    oTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(MyThreadFun);
    oTimer.Start();    

private static void MyThreadFun(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // inside here you read your query from the database
    // get the next email that must be send, 
    //  you send them, and mark them as send, log the errors and done.
}
```

why I select system timer:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx

#### more words

I use this in a more complex class and its work fine. What are the points that I have also made.

- Signaling the application stop, to wait for the timer to end.
- Use mutex and database for synchronize the works.

Comment: @KierenJohnstone Maybe I did not understand the question ?

Comment: "I am working on an assignment in asp.net to send notification email to users at specific intervals." - if the app isn't accessed for a day, it's not likely the worker processes will be there to run the timer

Comment: @KierenJohnstone ah, not if you start this timer at the application starts is never ends. I use it and its work fine.

Comment: In most production environments, a long-running worker process should be terminated - and if idle for a long time, it would be recycled too.  Results may vary, basically

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to exploit global.asax application events

On application startup event, create a thread (or task) into a static singleton variable in the global class.

The thread/task/workitem will have an endless loop while(true) {...} with your "service like" code inside.

You'll also want to put a Thread.Sleep(60000) in the loop so it doesn't eat unnecessary CPU cycles.

```
static void FakeService(object obj) {
    while(true) {
        try {
        // - get a list of users to send emails to
        // - check the current time and compare it to the interval to send a new email
        // - send emails
        // - update the last_email_sent time for the users
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // - log any exceptions
            // - choose to keep the loop (fake service) running or end it (return)
        }
        Thread.Sleep(60000); //run the code in this loop every ~60 seconds
    }
}
```

**EDIT** Because your task is more or less a simple timer job any of the ACID type concerns from an app pool reset or other error don't really apply, because it can just start up again and keep trucking along with any data corruption. But you could also use the thread to simply execute a request to an aspx or ashx that would hold your logic.

```
new WebClient().DownloadString("http://localhost/EmailJob.aspx");
```